# Vertically align div (no tables)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can horizontally align a div and all the content looks nice.
Looking to vertical align a div that does not contain any tables.
I tried setting margin positions to some negative values inside of the #container
but that sort of worked.  I know CSS isn't supporting this yet?

Here is my markup:

```css
body
{
    background: #777; /* gray */
    text-align: center;
}

#container 
{ 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 968px;
    text-align: left;
}

#toptab
{
    background: #f77; /* red */
    height: 14px;
    width: 968px;
}

#middletab
{
    background: #7f7; /* green */
    width: 968px;
}

#data
{
    width: 948px; /* 948 for the box plus we need 20 more px to handle the padding */
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-right 10px;
}

#bottomtab
{
    background: #77f; /* blue */
    height: 14px;
    width: 968px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="toptab"></div>
    <div id="middletab">
        <div id="data">
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
            The quick brown fox jumped over the big red bear.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomtab"></div>
</div>
```

Run the snippet above and click "full page" to see how it currently looks.
Basically, it looks great horizontally, but now I need it to also center vertically in the page.

The element that I want to align vertically is the #container div.  The effect would force the entire div and all sub divs to not only be horizontally aligned but also vertically.  I know this is possible and I know Andy Budd posted such a solution but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Do you mean vertically distributed/justified or just centering what's displayed vertically in the page?

Comment: @Eric the end result is the circular box with content should be in the middle of the page.  As of right now as you see the content is centered but centered to the top only.  I need to center it directly in the middle of the page.

Comment: As far as I've seen you have to do a bit of javascript unless you want a fixed-height page, which I doubt.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unless you have the ability to explicitly set the height of your container (which doesnt look like that's the case), there is **no cross browser solution** for vertically centering your DIV container.

Using a table is completely viable, but you have noted that this cannot be used.

If javascript is an option, we could easily remedy this for you. A jQuery plugin already exists for vertically aligning a container.

```
(function ($) {
    // VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION
    $.fn.vAlign = function() {
        return this.each(function(i){
            var ah = $(this).height();
            var ph = $(this).parent().height();
            var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
            $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And you would vertically align a DIV block like so:

```
$('#example').vAlign();
```

Taken from [Simple Vertical Align Plugin](http://www.seodenver.com/simple-vertical-align-plugin-for-jquery/).

Comment: @cballou There is no way that I'd be able to tell the height of the container, it could vary :(.  But if I assume the most its going to be is 500px say.  Using the markup provided what could I do ?

Comment: I tried this with no luck
#container 
{ 
 margin:0 auto;
 width:968px;
 text-align: left;
 
    position:absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 height:484px;
 margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
 margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/

}

Comment: @JonH: If it doesn't have a *fixed* height, you won't be able to make it vertically center without javascript.

Comment: @cballou +1 for that!  My only question is I haven't worked much with JQuery.  I understand the function needs to be within a head tag and do I just include jquery.js ?

Comment: Couldn't a vertical aligner be implemented via vanilla Javascript, with no need to utilize jQuery? Or is it just that using jQuery makes it easier?

Comment: this won't always work as at times, pre rendering, parent will be zero

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [Vertical Centering With CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) or [Vertically center content with CSS](http://www.vdotmedia.com/blog/vertically-center-content-with-css/) or [CSS Vertical Centering](http://www.brunildo.org/test/vertmiddle.html). Method 3 of first reference is the same as [CSS vertical center using float and clear](http://d-graff.de/fricca/center.html).

And it's surely a good idea to test the result with a service like [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/)

---

EDIT: I modified your CSS and markup to implement Method 3:

css:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align:center;
}

#floater {
  float: left;
  height:50%;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

#container
{
  clear:both;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:968px;
  text-align: left;
  height: 200px;
}

...
```

markup:

```
<body>
<div id="floater"></div>
<div id="container">

...
```

The drawback I see in this method is that **with CSS you have to know in advance the height of your content**, so that you can apply a negative margin of half this height to the floater. In the example I chose `200px`.

[See it in action](http://gregory.pakosz.fr/stackoverflow/1909753.html).

Comment: I don't need any articles I've read plenty.  I can't seem to get it to work with negative margin values.

Comment: If themeforest is ever unavailable, this response will be inadequate. Do you mind migrating the instructions over into your answer, and give credit to the original authors. That way people don't have to bounce from page to page to weigh the value of your response?

Comment: @Jonathan > good point although I don't like ripping stuff from others :/

Comment: funnily enough, I got upvoted by @JohnH for the links, and while I was busy implementing one of the techniques linked I got downvoted

Comment: Not by me gregory!!!  I thank you for your time and effort..I wish I could accept 2 answers!

Comment: It's not that important. It's just that I myself don't downvote an answer when there is obviously nothing wrong in it. If I feal it's not good enough I just don't vote up. Good luch with your site

Comment: I agree I've always wished SO had a section inside the person's profile to show you who was the latest votes whether up votes or down votes.  It would help to get feedback on a downvote.  For instance, force the user to leave a comment if he / she is downvoting.

Comment: and ironically my first thought was to suggest using jQuery :D

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, all with compromises.

- Use `position:absolute`, a fixed height, and `overflow:auto`.
- Use `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, and `vertical-align:middle`
- Use javascript

I think option #2 is pretty good.

**edit:** I don't think option 2 will work in IE.  You may be stuck with javascript if you want to keep the height dynamic.

Comment: Compromises cross browser compatibility: the whole IE family to be precise.

Comment: @cballou, ya I just thought of that and was editing my post as you were leaving your comment :P

Answer (score 2):

With pure CSS, this is **only** possible if the div has a **fixed** `height`. You can then `position` it `absolute` and set its `top` and `left` to `50%` and the `margin-top` and `margin-left` to the negative half of its `width` and `height` respectively.

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), just copy'n'paste'n'run. The border is purely presentational, the remaining styles are required.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 1909753</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        #content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px; /* Negative half of width. */
            margin-top: -100px; /* Negative half of height. */
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If there is no means of a fixed height, then you'll need to grasp Javascript and live with the fact that client will see the div quickly being shifted to middle during page load, which might cause a "wtf?" experience.

Answer (score 1):

Make a container div with style `display: table` and use the style `vertical-align: top` on inner elements that are `display: inline-block`

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/uzcrt/

Answer (score 0):

If your main container's height is fluid, your only reliable choice is to use JavaScript ("reliable" is debatable here, of course). In JavaScript, you must first find the height of the container, then the window height and adjust the top offset accordingly. Here's how you'd do it in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        var top = $(window).height() / 2 - $('#content').height() / 2;
        top = top < 0 ? 0 : top;
        $('#content').css('top', top);
    });
    $(window).resize();
});
```

And the CSS to make it work:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    /* Everything else is optional: */
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="#content">Content here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's still quite simple, and will work if the user has JavaScript enabled.

Comment: My only gripe with this function is it will only properly work if the element is a direct child of the BODY tag.  The plugin I posted utilizes it's parent container for calculating the centered position.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to do it without `display: table`.

this is the example:

HTML:

```
<div class="notificationArea">
    something
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notificationArea
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    left: 50%
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? There's a `display: table` rule in your CSS and it the div isn't centered vertically anyway...

Comment: The demo was showing another example for some reason. I replaced it by the acctual code.

Answer (score 0):

CSS class to align a element in middle of the screen:

```
.middle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; /*50% from top*/
    left: 50%; /*50% from left*/ 

    /*remove 50% of element width and height to align the element center in the position*/
    transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%); 
}
```

Now, add this class to HTML element