# Center div vertically using CSS

Tags: css

I´m currently working on a wordpress site where I want to center my page-wrap using CSS. I´ve tried to implement method 3 on this site without beeing successful.

Site: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

I´m using two different divs, one with the id of floater and one with the id of page-wrap. My css looks like this

```
#floater { float: left; height: 50%; margin-bottom: -481px; }

#page-wrap { clear: both; color: white; width: 1594px; height: 962px; margin: auto; position: relative; }
```

I also want to point out that inside my page-wrap div I have plenty of other divs to build my design (they also float to both left and right) if that affects the result in any way.

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FERNX/

Comment: Create a jsfiddle with an example of what you have

Comment: Here it is,I hope it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/FERNX/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically center elements in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023629/vertically-center-elements-in-css) . There are a ridiculous number of these questions on SO and the rest of the web.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#floater{
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

or

```
position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
margin-top: -25%;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know it's height the most east and straightforward solution is:

```
#page-wrap { position: absolute; height: 900px; top: 50%; margin-top: -450px; }
```

basically it says; position its top at 50% and substract half its height to have the div's center centered.