# Vertically centering elements

Tags: css

I need to vertically align with CSS multiple elements inside my header.

At the moment, I am using this structure:

```
-Header
 -Content div (This only set my width to 940 with paddings of 10px each side)
  -Element 1 (Height: Known, 50px)
  -Element 2 (Height: Unknown, bigger fonts)
  -Element 3 (Height: Unknown, smaller fonts)
```

So I need to vertically align to the middle (50% of my header - size of the element) all of my elements and I need to make it cross-browser compatible...

I've found some suggestion by searching such as using a floater div, however I had a hard time trying to align all of my elements since they are not all of the same size...

**EDIT**
As requested, here is my HTML and CSS:

***HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/mediadevis.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Accueil</li>
                    <li>Nos services</li>
                    <li>Notre compagnie</li>
                    <li>Nous joindre</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="lang">English</div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

***CSS:***

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #336699;
}

header{
    background-image:url('../IMG/bg_top.png');
    height: 90px;
}

nav > ul{
    float: left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding:0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

nav > ul > li{
    display: inline;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.content{
    margin: auto;
    width: 940px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#lang{
    float: left;
}

#logo{
    background-image:url('../IMG/logo.png');
    height: 50px;
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically center elements in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023629/vertically-center-elements-in-css)

Comment: you could use flexbox: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS code...

Comment: I took a look at the other thread, however the solution suggested used display: table... Which is not compatible with old IE versions...

Answer (score 1):

Try these suggestions from Smashing Magazine:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Specifically, try this code, using the TOP, LEFT, RIGHT, and BOTTOM properties to position your elements:

HTML

```
    <div class="magix">
      magix!
    </div>
    <div class="more-magix">
        More Magix!
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.magix{
            background: red;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 100px;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 100px;
        }
        .more-magix {
            background: blue;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 100px;
            left: 0;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: 500px;
            right: 0;
            width: 100px;
        }
```

OR, check out Chris Coiyer's methods:

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: I tried your Absolute Positioning proposition, however it seems like it only centers vertically and horizontally. Do you have any idea how to use this only for the vertial portion ?

Comment: Try substituting the margin:auto; for margin: auto, 0 auto, 0;

Comment: It sends my logo to the top-left completely

Comment: You mention compatibility with old versions of IE; what versions do you need to support? Every common method for vertical centering other than [negative margins](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/#Negative-Margins) and Javascript solutions are at least IE7+