# Cross browser div center alignment using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, alignment

What is the easiest way to align a `div` whose position is `relative` horizontally and vertically using CSS ? The width and the height of the `div` is unknown, i.e. it should work for every `div` dimension and in all major browsers. I mean center alignment.

I thought to make the horizontal alignment using:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

like I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cdTQw/).

Is this a good cross browser solution for horizontal alignment ?

How could I do the vertical alignment ?

Comment: When you say alignment, it is not clear with what you wish to align the div. Do you mean center the div?

Comment: Do you mean to vertically align div at the center

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean center alignment.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909753/vertically-align-div-no-tables/1909830#1909830

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Horizontal centering is only possible if the element's `width` is known, else the browser cannot figure where to start and end.

```
#content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is perfectly crossbrowser compatible.

Vertical centering is only possible if the element is positioned absolutely and has a known `height`. The absolute positioning would however break `margin: 0 auto;` so you need to approach this differently. You need to set its `top` and `left` to `50%` and the `margin-top` and `margin-left` to the **negative half** of its `width` and `height` respectively.

Here's a copy'n'paste'n'runnable example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2935404</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        #content {
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px; /* Negative half of width. */
            margin-top: -100px; /* Negative half of height. */
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

That said, vertical centering is usually seldom applied in real world.

If the width and height are really unknown beforehand, then you'll need to grab Javascript/jQuery to set the `margin-left` and `margin-top` values and live with the fact that client will see the div quickly be shifted during page load, which might cause a "wtf?" experience.

Comment: Note that you have to run IE in Standards mode for this to work (in Quirks mode, you'll have to use `text-align: center` on the parent element to center a div horizontally).

Comment: Quirks mode is never an option for modern web pages so it's not worth consideration.

Comment: @Rob: though I hate to start a flame war about this (no one dies of Quirks mode), I once had to use Quirks mode in a web app to use the [border-box box model](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) in IE.

Comment: @Marcel: the div should then be set to `display: inline`, because `text-align` only applies on `inline` elements. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281087/center-a-div-in-css-text-align-is-not-the-answer/2281107#2281107). And indeed, you don't want to have it run in quirks mode. There's no reason to do so.

Comment: If you think there is *never* a reason to revert to quirks mode, how would you solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857412/ie6-frame-layout-with-100-height-and-scrollbars) without using CSS expressions (and without using frames, of course)?

Comment: @Marcel: that's a nice one. I would just argument, is there a reason to support an over a decade old browser? But this is likely not valid for the OP in question :)

Comment: Well, it's old, but still overly used. A company I work for used IE 6 until not too long ago and I encounter the old man at several other companies and places like public libraries, etc. Complaining everywhere that they should use a newer browser is of course not a solution (and I highly doubt it will improve things, nor will it increase my rep). I also don't want those horrible “Update your browser, I will not work” messages, as I'll cut my own fingers (not being able to access my app everywhere). Also read http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2010/jan/22/internet-explorer-nhs-vulnerability

Comment: Hello... Sorry for this is a little bit late. I tried the answer of BalusC, and it worked fine. But in my case I need 'my form' to be in the center, because I want to be able to scroll to any place in the form if much 'zoom in' is applied... I simply replaced the CSS of the div tag (content) with the css of my form tag. But the problem is still exist. My problem is that when I zoom in (whatever is the browser that I use) I lose the upper left part of the form (and I am not able to scroll to it). Is there a way to get this solved? Thank you.

Comment: @BalusC: Does this mean that this solution is fully compatible with IE6 in non-quirks-mode? No other tricks needed?

Comment: @BalusC: Yeah, I'm sorry. I wanted to test it myself, but didn't have my IE6 machine available, so I just asked .. And forgot all about browsershots.org .. Awkward. But thanks :)

Comment: The technical term for the "wtf?" experience you refer to is the FOUC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content

Answer (score 7):

"Vertical centering is only possible if the element is positioned absolutely and has a known height." – This statement is not exactly correct.

You can try and use `display:inline-block;` and its possibility to be aligned vertically within its parent's box. This technique allows you to align element without knowing its height and width, although it requires you to know parent's height, at the least.

If your HTML is this;

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="aligned-middle" class="inline-block">Middleman</div>
    <div class="strut inline-block">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

And your CSS is:

```
#container {
    /* essential for alignment */
    height:300px;
    line-height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    /* decoration */
    background:#eee;
}
    #aligned-middle {
        /* essential for alignment */
        vertical-align:middle;
        /* decoration */
        background:#ccc;
        /* perhaps, reapply inherited values, so your content is styled properly */
        line-height:1.5;
        text-align:left;
    }
    /* this block makes all the "magic", according to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align specification: "The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge." */
    #container .strut {
        /* parent's height */
        height:300px;
    }
.inline-block {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;/* for IE < 8 */
    *zoom:1;/* for IE < 8 */
}
```

Then #aligned-middle will be centered within #container. This is the simplest use of this technique, but it's a nice one to be familiar with.

Rules marked with "/* for IE < 8 */" should be placed in a separate stylsheet, via use of conditional comments.

You can view a working example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/UXKcA/3/

edit: (this particular snippet tested in ie6 and ff3.6, but I use this a lot, it's pretty cross-browser. if you would need support for ff < 3, you would also need to add `display:-moz-inline-stack;` under `display:inline-block;` within `.inline-block` rule.)

Answer (score 2):

Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh7RE/)**</kbd>

Set following **two** things

1. HTML **align** attribute value **center**
2. CSS **margin-left** and **margin-right** properties value set **auto**

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
     #setcenter{
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;    
          // margin: 0px auto; shorthand property
     }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div align="center" id="setcenter">
   This is some text!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "If the width and height are really unknown beforehand, then you'll
>   need to grab Javascript/jQuery to set the margin-left and margin-top
>   values and live with the fact that client will see the div quickly be
>   shifted during page load, which might cause a "wtf?" experience."

You could `.hide()` the div when the DOM is ready, wait for the page to load, set the div `margin-left` and `margin-top` values, and `.show()` the div again.

```
$(function(){
   $("#content").hide();
)};
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $("#content").getDimSetMargins();
   $("#content").show();
});
```

Comment: bad practice, but if allready, hide it in the css, and only show it when jq is loaded.