# How to center a block level element vertically?

Tags: html, center, vertical-alignment

Say I have a  like so:

```
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `margin-*` attributes instruct the table to center itself within its parent element.

Is there a similar way to center the element vertically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross browser div center alignment using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935404/cross-browser-div-center-alignment-using-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very often requested thing to do. There's no simple way to do vertical alignment. There's the `vertical-align` attribute, but it's for line-alignment of an inline element. Check out [this link](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) for different ways to do vertical-centering.

Edit: [Here's another](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) good link to get you started.

Comment: Haha, you were first so you get dibs. :) I'll delete mine.

Comment: And I complained when they took out the `<center>` tag!

Comment: @attack - Haha, I was just re-loading to delete mine and saw yours disappear. Cheers!

Comment: @George - It can be quite a pain to center but I agree with the 2nd link where `Method 3` is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who stumbles across this in search of a solution to a similar question, I've written a jQuery plugin that can center any block element very easily. This is not to promote my own project, I honestly just want to help out and contribute where I can. There's a link and demo [here](http://tailorfit.me).

Comment: Blaming DNS Propagation. :p Check now?