# Div content alignment query

Tags: css, html, alignment, vertical-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertically align div (no tables)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909753/vertically-align-div-no-tables)

I have a `div` and I would like to align all content within this `div` - currently an `h1` tag vertically centre how would I do this?

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
  width:100%;
}
div h1{
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you actually searched this on stackoverflow? This same question is asked and answered nearly every day. [Vertically Align Div Content](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertically+align+div+content&submit=search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no cross browser solution for vertically centering your DIV container, but there is a jQuery plugin that allows you to do this:

`(function ($) {

    // VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION

    $.fn.vAlign = function() {

        return this.each(function(i){

            var ah = $(this).height();

            var ph = $(this).parent().height();

            var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;

            $(this).css('margin-top', mh);

        });

    };

})(jQuery);`

Then you can add this Javascript:

`$(document).ready(function() {

$('div h1').vAlign();

});`