# align the website to vertically middle to the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web site which is of height 490px. I need to get the entire website to the vertically middle to the browser.

Any suggestion!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align div (no tables)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909753/vertically-align-div-no-tables) and hundreds upon hundreds of others here on SO and the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body style="text-align: center">
    <div style="text-align: left; width: 950px">content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I need vertical alignment not horzontal

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>vertical align</title>
    <style>
      * {margin:0px;padding:0px}
      #content {height:490px; width:960px; position:absolute; border: 2px #000 solid}
    </style>
    <script>
      function resize(){
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
          var bodyHeight = window.getComputedStyle(body).height.replace('px','');
        }else if(body.runtimeStyle){
          var bodyHeight = body.offsetHeight;
        }
        content.style.top = (bodyHeight - 490)/2 + 'px';
      }
      window.onresize = window.onload = resize;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#content{ 
    height: 490px; 
    margin-top: -245px; 
    top: 50% 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The traditional method would be to use a table and set `vertical-align:middle;`, but using tables for layout is now considered bad practice. The new solution is the flexible box layout, but that still isn't widely supported. So, here's an intermediate solution. It's a little hackish, but it gets the job done in every browser and doesn't use tables. ([live demo](http://pastehtml.com/view/bmstt3sg3.html))

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>positioning test</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
      *        {margin:0; padding:0;}
      body     {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%;}
      #pad     {height:50%; min-height:245px;}
      #content {height:490px; margin-top:-245px;
                background:#f88; border:2px solid #000;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='pad'></div>
    <div id='content'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please don't use javascript for this - it's a very bad idea to use javascript for the layout unless absolutely necessary, and for this it is certainly not necessary. Also, note that you cannot combine the two divs and simply set `#content {position:absolute; top:50%;}`, as `#pad` must have the correct `min-height`, otherwise some content will be hidden in windows shorter than 490px (494px in the example).

Answer (score 0):

Link to vertical alignment page is here....[Here](http://www.vdotmedia.com/demo/css-vertically-center.html)

just view page source & you will come to know how to do it