# How to put table in the center of the page using CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I am using the following code. How to put this table in the center of the page using CSS?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>The Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
                <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of many other questions e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281087/center-a-div-in-css

Comment: horizontally centered? vertically centered? both?

Comment: Both horizontally and vertically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically align div (no tables)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909753/vertically-align-div-no-tables)

Answer (score 108):

### Edit for 2022: Flexbox Please

Use Flexbox, instructions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

.box div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

2021 answer preserved below.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTTpN/1/)

Vertically aligning block elements is not the most trivial thing to do. Some methods below.

- [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)
- [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

Comment: Hey, but this only centered it horizontally and not vertically. Also, what is margin: 0 auto?

Comment: @CodeBlue - then see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909753/vertically-align-div-no-tables

Answer (score 31):

You can try using the following CSS:

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;            
}​
```

Comment: Some bandwith can be saved by removing `px`.

Answer (score 12):

**1) Setting horizontal alignment to auto in CSS**

`margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;`

**2) Get vertical alignment to centre of the page add following to css**

`html, body {
        width: 100%;
}`

For example :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
 table.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
}

</style>
<title>Table with css</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
        </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Was trapped in same situation because of HTML4 and HTML5 conflicts and `alignment="centre"` was absolute in HTML5.

Answer (score 8):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
 table.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>
<title>Table with css</title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <th>SNO</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>yazali</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you where asking about the table to complete center, like some thing in total center.,
you can apply the following code.

```
margin: 0px auto;
margin-top: 13%;
```

this code in css will let you put your table like floating.
Tell me if it helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "display: flex;".

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex; /* WIDTH and HEIGHT are required*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="lightSquare"></button></td>
            <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

simply put it in the div then control that div whit css:

```
<div class="your_position">
  <table>
  </table>
</div>
```